# "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." when trying to create a new Azure AD App programmatically

Tags: azure-active-directory

Im trying to create an Azure AD App programmatically (C#-script)
I have wrapped the call to AddApplicationAsync in a try-catch

and when I run it I get exception message "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",

```
public void CreateNewClientApplication(string pName, Guid pResourceAppId)
        {
            var newClientApp = new Application();
            newClientApp.DisplayName = pName;
            newClientApp.ReplyUrls.Add(CreateDummyReplyUrl(pName));

            newClientApp.PasswordCredentials = new List<PasswordCredential>() {
                new PasswordCredential()
                {
                    Value = "xxxxxxxxx",
                    KeyId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(2),
                }
            };

            RequiredResourceAccess resource = new RequiredResourceAccess();
            resource.ResourceAppId = pResourceAppId.ToString();
            newClientApp.RequiredResourceAccess.Add(resource);

            var activeDirectoryClient = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
            try
            {
                activeDirectoryClient.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(newClientApp).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 // EXCEPTION-MESSAGE: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
            }

        }
```

**So my question is, what permissions are required?** 
I have these

[image]

Comment: A common error is that you forget to click on the "Grant Permission" button after you saved the permissions. Did you hit the button?

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for your reply. Yes 100%, Im not an admin on that Azure Portal and it was granted on my vacation, I can only see the result of what admin did grant

Comment: Well, I think read and write all applications should be enough - so this should work. You could ask your admin to hit the Grant permission button again.

Comment: That is clearly not the problem. Thanks for your input

Comment: Hmm, sorry for being so dismissive. I have tested this on another Azure Portal, where I am admin, and given myself same permissions (not forgetting the Grant-button). This works past the permissions. I have asked our helpdesk to redo the granting and post again when that is done